# External Assets Not PIcked Up By Play

Tags: scala, playframework

Can somebody explain to me why Play does not pick up external assets that are specified in the head of a HTML page?

If I have a standalone web page as shown below, the CSS is picked up and the button is rendered correctly:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Shrine (MDC Web Example App)</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://material.io/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <button class="foo-button mdc-button">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Correctly Rendered Button:

[image]

However, if I put almost exactly the same code in a Play project it does not pick up the CSS (code below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        @* Here's where we render the page title `String`. *@
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
          <button class="foo-button mdc-button">Button</button>
        </body>
</html>
```

Button Not Rendered with CSS Applied:

[image]

The only difference is that I have had to escape the "@" as follows:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
```

If I put all the CSS that the url points to into a separate file in the public/stylesheets folder of the Play project and then reference it as below then the CSS is picked up and the button is rendered correctly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/foo.css")">
```

Can somebody explain the way Play is working here? Why does it do this? Or is that by escaping the ampersand the external CSS is not picked up?

UPDATE

I just checked in Chrome, and I get this message when loading the page via Play:

> Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: I believe you will have a 404 for that request to `material-components-web.min.css` with the escaped @. What error do you get in Play if you don't escape the @?

Comment: Did you try `https://unpkg.com/material-components-web%40latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css`

Comment: I just tried that, same problem with the same message

Comment: I think it is a Chrome issue rather than a Play issue

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/

Comment: It's actually doing a good thing by blocking this. From a security point of view, it would be best to bundle the CSS and JS with the Play project so that it is trusted.

Comment: Ye, you could just do that. Out of curiosity try adding this meta - `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />`

Comment: That should have worked as it is instructs the browser to bypass the security policy but it didn't work - same message.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you cannot reference a file (js, css, etc.) that comes from another source, other than your running host.

**Why is that?**  Well this is because of security reasons: all the scripts/styles/etc should be running from your host (either `localhost` or `example.com`).

**Solution**: If you want to access, external resources, you could `disable` the security headers filter within `application.conf`:

```
play.filters.disables += "play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter"
```

**Note**: This is not recommended in because of security risks.

Additional read from documentation: [security headers in Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SecurityHeaders).